# Install S3 Log Storage Plugin for Rundeck Clustering

Tags: rundeck

I have downloaded the S3 log storage Plugin from: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-s3-log-plugin.

My servers donot have external internet access.
**Can I get some steps to install and build Rundeck Plugin: rundeck-s3-log-plugin without internet access.**

I did download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-bin.zip
And changed the url location for gradle to a file location in "gradle-wrapper.properties"
`distributionUrl=file:///<downloaded location>/gradle-2.12-bin.zip`

Started the build:
`./gradlew clean build`
.
.
.
.
`Unzipping /var/lib/rundeck/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.12-bin/4owykoqmt3srsqxlu42r1x4w9/gradle-2.12-bin.zip to /var/lib/rundeck/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.12-bin/4owykoqmt3srsqxlu42r1x4w9`

`Set executable permissions for: /var/lib/rundeck/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.12-bin/4owykoqmt3srsqxlu42r1x4w9/gradle-2.12/bin/gradle`

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`
`* Where:`
`Build file '/rpms/rundeck-s3-log-plugin-master/build.gradle' line: 9`
`* What went wrong:`
`Error resolving plugin [id: 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release', version: '1.10.0']`
`> Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.12/plugin/use/pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release/1.10.0'.`
   `> plugins.gradle.org: Name or service not known`

`* Try:`
`Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`

`BUILD FAILED`

Here gradle is trying to resolve plugin url: https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.12/plugin/use/pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release/1.10.0

Further more, it may require internet for build to complete. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

For clustering the best approach is to use Rundeck Enterprise, Enterprise is specific designed for [that](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/cluster/). So, you don't need to compile the plugin to use it "offline" you can download the prebuilt jar file from [here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-s3-log-plugin/releases/download/v1.0.11/rundeck-s3-log-plugin-1.0.11.jar), put it on [libext](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/installing.html) directory, and use it with your local storage service (like [Minio](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/cluster/logstore/#logstore)).